# c++ Function inside Thread function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I am creating a boost thread in the following manner.

```
static void* ThreadFuncCall(void *arg) { return ((TestClass*)arg)->Thread1Func((TestClass*)arg
Thread1 = new boost::thread((boost::bind(&TestClass::ThreadFuncCall, this)));

void* TestClass::Thread1Func(TestClass* testClass){
    //Accessing the member variables here
    testClass->m_active = true;
    //call another function here
}
```

And inside the `Thread1Func` I want to call another function to which I want to pass the object of `TestClass` like I have passed to `ThreadFuncCall`.

I want to know whether we can have a call to another function inside a thread function?

And if we can, Then how do I pass the object of `TestClass` to it?

Comment: where is this 'another function' defined?

Comment: within the thread function, can't u call 'testClass->functionname()'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call a function from another function. The function call will be executed in the same thread as the original function. To pass a pointer to the class to the another function, do the same thing you did with ThreadFunc1.

```
void* TestClass::Thread1Func(TestClass* testClass){
    //Accessing the member variables here
    testClass->m_active = true;
    //call another function here
    int i = function1(testClass, "hello world");
}

int function1(TestClass* testClass, char* text){
    testClass->printText(text);
    return 7;
}
```